# Is a found Steed allowed an independent destination and creature when targeted by Dimension Door?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, mount

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/182169/how-does-the-dimension-door-spell-interact-with-a-mount-summoned-by-the-find-ste) asks whether a creature summoned by *[Find Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed)* or *[Find Greater Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed)* can be brought with the caster when the caster uses *[Dimension Door](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door)*.

I agree with the [accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/182171/23547), which says that:

(1) Assuming a Medium caster, a size Large Steed could not be brought along as a willing creature due to the wording of the *Dimension Door* spell, but

(2) If the caster is mounted on the steed, the *Find Steed* ability to "make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed" means that even a larger-than-caster sized steed could be affected when the caster targeted only themselves.

Assuming that this is the correct interpretation, and that the steed is *not* the willing creature brought along but *rather* an independent target of the spell, do all of the features of the spell also affect it independently?

For example, can it choose ***its own* destination** for the *dimension door* as a separate location from the one chosen by the caster?

And can it bring ***its own* willing creature** along with it?

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks for the edit.  I own the print copy of Xanathar's, not the digital.  When I search the spell in D&D Beyond, the marketplace is what I get.  How do I get the correct address to link to when I cannot search for / land on that address?

Comment: You can use the copy link function in the search results.

Comment: @Kirt I construct it from the name: the link for a spell is gonna be under `/spells/` and then the name of the spell with hyphens replacing spaces (omitting apostrophes altogether). Alternately, you could just skip the link, it isn't necessary, just a convenience.

Comment: reminds me of [my first question on this site](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62330/22566) - and this is one of the few good questions (to my tastes) that has cropped up lately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming as the question does that you can use *dimension door* like this with a found steed:<sup>1</sup>

#### *Dimension door* targets the steed in the same way that it targets the caster.

*Find (greater) steed* states:

> While mounted on your steed, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target your steed.

The obvious application of this feature is this: *the spell targets the steed in the same way that it targets the caster*. Which is:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot within range.

So both the caster, *and the steed*, are subject to this effect, and all of the effects that follow in the spell description. To put it another way, once you have chosen to have *dimension door* also target the steed, the effect is resolved as if the steed had also cast *dimension door* at the same time. The entire spell description applies independently to the caster and the steed (though for the purposes of features like *counterspell*, the steed is not treated as having cast the spell).

---

<sup>1</sup> However, I cannot help but shamelessly plug [my objection to this assumption](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/182170/62294).