# Found Greater Steed and removing a Hat of Disguise

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, targeting, mount

I don't regret allowing the party Bard to take *[Find Greater Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-greater-steed)* as a Magical Secret, but I am starting to realize it may be a perennial source of [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191220/is-a-found-steed-allowed-an-independent-destination-and-creature-when-targeted-b).

In our last session, the Bard summoned her steed:

> While mounted on it, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target the mount.

While mounted, she used her *[Hat of Disguise](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/hat-of-disguise)* to cast the *[Disguise Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self)* spell,

> While wearing this hat, you can use an action to cast the *disguise self* spell from it at will.

targeting only herself and thus creating an independent cast of the spell on the mount.  While the original spell has a duration of 1 Hour, since it was cast from the *Hat* it is also subject to

> The spell ends if the hat is removed.

The spell on the Bard will certainly end if the *hat* is removed - but will the replicated and independent spell targeting the mount **also** end when the *Hat* is removed from the bard?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### The spell is only cast once, so when it ends, it ends for both the bard and the mount.

Nothing in the description of *find greater steed* indicates that *disguise self* is cast more than once:

> While mounted on it, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you *also target the mount.*

It only makes the steed an additional target of the single spell you cast; *it is not a “replicated and independent spell targeting the mount”*. You cast one spell, and that one spell targets yourself and your steed. Then, *disguise self* says:

> You make yourself--including your clothing, armor, weapons, and other belongings on your person--look different *until the spell ends*

So when the spell ends, the disguise effect ends. Since the spell ends when you remove the hat, the effect ends on both the bard and the steed at that moment.

Comment: Having read your answer, I agree that this is a single spell with two targets.  But if the bard and steed then separate, is there any limit to the distance between them for the hat removal to end the spell on the Steed?  Would it work if the Steed was subsequently on another plane of existence than the hat, possibly one with a different flow of time?  Is this spooky action at a distance?

Comment: @Kirt Yeah, spooky action is a good way to describe. You’re on the right track anticipating weird interactions. I played a bard with *find greater steed* and I just had conversations with my DM throughout the week about how fgs would interact with different spells, so that when it came time to select new spells, I already had a ruling on how they would function with fgs.

Comment: That description of "self" is typical for spells. I posit that claiming a steed counts as wearable item is a matter of magical semantics which *Find Greater Steed* loosens.