# Found Greater Steed and Mislead

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, mount

The same bard who was [using a *Hat of Disguise* on her Found Greater Steed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191460/found-steed-and-removing-a-hat-of-disguise) is now thinking of picking up *Mislead*.

I agree with the [accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/191461/23547) on the [previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191460/found-steed-and-removing-a-hat-of-disguise), that when *Find Greater Steed* says:

> While mounted on it, you can make any spell you cast that targets only you also target the mount

that means there is only *one* spell cast, it just has two targets.

[*Mislead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mislead) says:

> an illusory double of you appears where you are standing. The double lasts for the duration...
> You can use your action to move your illusory double up to twice your speed and make it gesture, speak, and behave in whatever way you choose.

If the bard casts *Mislead* on herself while mounted, she can extend the *Mislead* to the Steed.  As one spell with two targets, does the bard need one action from herself to run *both* illusory doubles, or does she run her own double with one action, and the Steed needs *its* action to run its own double?

Comment: Related: [How does the Dimension Door spell interact with a mount summoned by the Find Steed or Find Greater Steed spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/182169/how-does-the-dimension-door-spell-interact-with-a-mount-summoned-by-the-find-ste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The text "You can use your action to move your illusory double" is a spell effect upon the targeted creature(s).

If the spell *normally* included multiple targets, it would read that each *target* could use their action to move their illusory double.

Normally, you would cast the spell, and a duplicate of yourself would appear while you become invisible, that you can control with your action. In the case of find steed, you cast the spell, and you and your steed *each* get a duplicate while turning invisible, which you can *each* control with your actions.

One could argue this is an interpretation, but the alternative conclusion is that since the steed isn't "you", no one can control its duplicate, and it becomes an uncontrollable, immobile illusion. In this case, the spell Mislead is specifically hamstrung despite qualifying to work with Find Greater Steed's spell-share in the first place. This doesn't seem like design intention.